# How to put the range of dates in a specific format?

Tags: scala, jodatime

I am using Joda time to generate a range of dates as follows:

```
val now = DateTime.now
(0 until 5).map(now.minusDays(_)).foreach(println)
```

How can I parse the generated dates to `yyyy-MM-dd` format. I was getting the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format" when using `DateTimeFormat`:

```
val dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
(0 until 5).map(now.minusDays(_)).foreach(d=>dtf.parseDateTime(d.toString))
```

Comment: As a side note, you may be interested in ditching `joda-time`, which has been deprecated by its authors in March 2014, after JSR-310 (`java.time`) made its way into the first release of Java 8. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
val now = DateTime.now
(0 until 5).map(now.minusDays(_)).map(d=> d.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Comment: Right - you can just put string pattern.